# Is it possible to have a .join function and a % (var) next to a print statement in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im currently trying to make a message display a list and then a variable in the same line:

```
recipents = ['email@email.com']
sent = 1
print "%s Email sent to: " + ', ' % (sent).join(recipients)
```

I have tried moving the "% (sent)" behind the .join function but nothing will work. I know that i could just make two print statements but that would print two lines which i don't want. I normally code in python 3, but i had to use python 2 for this. 
*I have to use the .join function because i am calling those from a list.*

The best-case scenario output would be

```
Email sent to: mail@mail.com, mail2@mail.com (1)
```

**To clarify, the sent part above is a variable**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  In particular, (1) `sent` is undefined; (2) "nothing will work" is not a problem specification; (3) Show your best attempt and the failing output.

Comment: Why do you have the `%` at the beginning of the format string if you want the substitution at the end?

Comment: May I ask why py2 for this?

Comment: isnt %s the substitution for putting in a variable later? im referring to this: print "My name is %s " % ('Bob')

Comment: Why you try to join `sent` (1) with the recipients ?

Comment: ok, so each time the program sends one email, it sends that message, and add one to "sent" . so it should say: {Email sent to: mail@mail.com, @mail2@mail.com (1)} the next message should say the same but instead of it being one, its 2. It makes it easier to see how many emails have been sent. Otherwise i wouldnt use a variable. (also i dont know how to add code blocks to comments so please forgive me for this bad formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the substitution at the end of the `Email sent to:` string, not the beginning.

`sent` should be provided as a second argument to the `%` operator,

So the format string should be `"Email sent to: %s (%s)"`. Then you can use the result of `join` as the value that will be substituted for the first `%s`, and `sent` for the second `%s`.

```
print "Email sent to: %s (%s)" % (",".join(recipients), sent)
```

Comment: im sorry for the misinformation on my side, the "sent" part is supposed to be a variable, not a string. My thread has been amended accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
recipients = ['mail@mail.com', 'mail2@mail.com']
print "Email sent to: " + ', '.join(recipients) + ' (sent)'
```

result:

```
>>> Email sent to: mail@mail.com, mail2@mail.com (sent)
```

Comment: im sorry for the misinformation on my side, the "sent" part is supposed to be a variable, not a string.

Comment: @Curio, `str(sent)` should turn the variable to string. So `Email sent to: " + ', '.join(recipients) + str(sent)`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
print(" Email sent to: %s (sent)"  % ' '.join(recipients))
```